# Multitouch to singletouch on touchscreen Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, touchscreen, multi-touch

I have a custom version of VLC (which I didn't work on so I have no idea what's been done to it) and this version doesn't support multi point interpretation. 
I haven't found an answer on how to switch from multi point interpretation to single point interpretation.

If anyone has an idea, please, let me know.

If you need any files, I'd gladly share them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So VLC (2.2.2) doesn't support multitouch so in order to interact with DVD menu, I installed `touchegg` and configured an action for one finger only.

Works like a charm now.

install touchegg : `sudo apt-get install touchegg`

my touchegg.conf

```
<touchégg>

<settings>
    <property name="composed_gestures_time">0</property>
</settings>


<application name="vlc, VLC, Vlc">

<gesture type="TAP" fingers="1" direction="">
        <action type="MOUSE_CLICK">BUTTON=1</action>
    </gesture>

</application>
```